# Is Mutants and Masterminds 3e (going to be) OGL?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e, ogl

So I've been flipping through the [DC Adventures](http://www.mutantsandmasterminds.com/dc_adventures/) rulebook, and a lot of the terms are changing up: "feat" is now "advantage" for example... is this part of a move away from the OGL on the part of Green Ronin? Will future versions of Mutants and Masterminds *not* be OGL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe so.  I can't find where they state that outright, but they discuss [the future of the M&M Superlink license](http://www.mutantsandmasterminds.com/mutants_masterminds_news_archives/2010/05/mm_superlink_to.php) and say it'll be just like [True20 licensing](http://true20.com/licensing-true20.php), and True20 is OGL at the core.

Oh, actually, [Steve Kenson stated explicitly on RPGNet](http://forum.rpg.net/showpost.php?p=12174674&postcount=381) that yes, it will be.

The OGC portion of the M&M 3E rules can be found at http://www.d20herosrd.com/ (site working as of March 16, 2015).  While this site may not be available in the future, the OGC license does not have an expiration date.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I figured I'd improve this answer with the link to the content in question, now that it exists.